# Buildroot Package Makefile: How to fetch the most recent commit from git?

Tags: buildroot

I am working on adding my own module to the build of buildroot using $BR2_External. The make file of my package is as follows,

```
##############################################################
#
# GPIO
#
##############################################################

GPIO_VERSION = '2851a05c9b613c1736f79faa185a11118b229852'

GPIO_SITE = '<URL of git repo>'
GPIO_SITE_METHOD = git
GPIO_GIT_SUBMODULES = YES

GPIO_MODULE_SUBDIRS = GPIO_driver/
# GPIO_MODULE_SUBDIRS += GPIO_driver/

# define LDD_BUILD_CMDS
#   $(MAKE) $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) -C $(@D)/misc-modules
#   $(MAKE) $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) -C $(@D)/scull
# endef
#
# # TODO add your writer, finder and finder-test utilities/scripts to the installation steps below

define GPIO_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS

    #module
    # $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(@D)/01_simple_LKM/*  $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(@D)/GPIO_driver/*  $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin

endef

$(eval $(kernel-module))
$(eval $(generic-package))
```

This make file always pulls only a specific commit (mentioned in GPIO_VERSION variable) from gitHub. This is getting a little frustrating as, everytime I push new code to git I have to update the make file with the new commit number as well. So, is there any way to write the make file such that the most recent commit is pulled.

Comment: Have you looked at [8.14.6. Using Buildroot during development](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_advanced_usage) i.e. using `local.mk`?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the version to a branch name (local or remote) like this:

```
GPIO_VERSION = origin/master # This will use HEAD of origin/master.
```

However, you will now have to force Buildroot to pull the latest changes (each time you push new commits to the GPIO repo).

```
$ make gpio-dirclean  # Remove all GPIO build output
$ rm -fr dl/gpio      # Remove the downloaded GPIO source code (git project)
$ make gpio           # Build the GPIO project (will download from the HEAD of your branch)
```